# CSV file + set CSV parameters and values in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I have the following CSV file:

```
Alabama,Alaska,Arizona,Arkansas,California,Colorado,Connecticut,Delaware,Florida,Georgia,Hawaii,Idaho,Illinois,Indiana,Iowa
1000,"1 0 0 1",1002,1002,1003,1004,1005,"1 0 0 6",1007,1008,1009,1010,1011,1012,1013
100,101,102,102,103,104,105,"1 0 6 2",107,108,109,110,111,112,113
10001,10011,10021,10021,10031,10041,10051,10061,10071,10081,10091,10101,10111,10121,10131
.
.
.
.
```

My target is to set the CSV parameters ( all states in CSV ) with their values in my bash script

for example

```
#!/bin/bash

Alabama=1000
.
.
.
Iowa=1013
```

so in my bash script I can read each parameter

example

```
 echo $Alabama
 1000
```

First I just tried to write the following (wrong) code, in order to set the parameters with their values:

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=1

for CSV_COLUMN in Alabama  Alaska  Arizona Arkansas  California  Colorado  Connecticut Delaware Florida  Georgia  Hawaii  Idaho  Illinois  Indiana  Iowa 
do
  export $CSV_COLUMN=` echo $CSV_LINE | cut -d',' -f$counter `
  counter=$counter+1
done
```

The test should be (from the bash script)

```
echo $Alabama
1000
```

How should I change my code in order to implement my idea?

Comment: Please read [this page](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for instructions on formatting your posts on Unix.SE. Are the extra spaces part of your input file? Why do you have many more values than states?

Comment: about you last question - because the defintion of each line is diff , but the parameters are the same for each line

Comment: I'm sorry, that makes no sense to me. What definition? What parameters? Do you want to go through the file and assign the values to the variables for each line?

Comment: Yes that I want - to go through the CSV file and assign the values to the variables in my BASH SCRIPT , thx

Comment: Never mind, I did it for you. The main issue is that having spaces _affects the code you need to write_ so we need to know that the example input you post is exactly as you show it, spaces included. I also removed other needless spaces from your question to make it easier to read without needing to scroll on small devices.

Comment: If you are using bash version 4+, have you considered using a single _associative array_ instead of defining a whole bunch of individual named variables?

Comment: Could you tell us what you're actually trying to do? Having a variable named `$ALABAMA` is not very useful since you will never see that name written, it would only be available to the program internally. I think what you're after will be solved by using arrays but please explain what kind of processing your script will be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) sn[i]=$i }
         NR==2 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print sn[i] "=" $i; exit }' states
```

where `states` is your file, will output

```
Alabama=1000
Alaska="1 0 0 1"
Arizona=1002
Arkansas=1002
California=1003
Colorado=1004
Connecticut=1005
Delaware="1 0 0 6"
Florida=1007
Georgia=1008
Hawaii=1009
Idaho=1010
Illinois=1011
Indiana=1012
Iowa=1013
```

- `-F,` sets `awk`’s field separator to `,`.
- `NR==1` means “do the following on the first record (line) only”; `NR==2` means the second line.
- The (first) `for` loop looks at each field in the first row and assigns the values (state names) to the `sn` array: `sn[1]=Alabama`, `sn[2]=Alaska`, …).
- The second `for` loop looks at each (comma-delimited) field in the second row and pairs it with the corresponding state name (from the first line) and an `=`, as shown above.
- Then we `exit`, so `awk` doesn’t need to read the rest of the file.

So

```
eval $(awk -F, 'NR==1 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) sn[i]=$i }
                NR==2 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print sn[i] "=" $i; exit }' states)
```

will capture that output and interpret it as a series of commands. 
Done.

---

If you’re determined to use a shell loop and the `cut` command, consider

```
values=$(sed -n '2p;2q' states)
counter=1
for state_name in $(sed 's/,/ /g;1q' states)
do
    eval $state_name=$(echo "$values" | cut -d, -f$counter)
    counter=$((counter+1))
done
```

Or you could list the state names explicitly, as you did in your example/attempt
(`for var in Alabama  Alaska Arizona Arkansas …`). 
But why would you want to duplicate your data in your code when it’s already in the file? 
And you could eliminate the `values` variable and do

```
eval $state_name=$(sed -n '2p;2q' states | cut -d, -f$counter)
```

in the loop, but that would require reading the `states` file 50 times instead of once. 
(Or 51 times instead of twice,
if you count the `for state_name in $(sed 's/,/ /g;1q' states)` statement.)

Comment: You are, of course, free to have whatever opinion you want, but I don’t understand what you’re talking about. Search the question and the other answer for `103` and `10001` – the only place they appear is in the question, in the display of the input file (3rd and 4th lines). The OP never said anything about doing anything with those values, and neither did @chaos.

Answer (score 1):

Use this line:

```
read `sed -e 's/,/ /g' -e '1q;d' file` < <(sed -e 's/\ /\\\ /g' -e 's/"//g' -e 's/,/ /g' -e '2q;d' file)
```

**Explanation**:

- The first `sed` command causes that only the first line of the file is printed and commas (`,`) are replaced with spaces: `Alabama Alaska Arizona Arkansas California ...`
- The second sed command does the same with the second line (it seems in your question that you only want the values of the second line): `1000 1001 1002 1002 ...`.
- `read -r` assignes the first list with the second.

After you can test the values with `echo`:

```
echo $Alabama
1000
echo $Alaska
1 0 0 1
echo $Georgia
1008
```

Comment: I want to add something else , some times I have CSV as 1000, "10 11 22 33" , 1001 , 1002   , how we can support the strings between the "   "

Comment: see my update question

Comment: @maihabunash I changed the line a bit, see my updated answer.

Comment: need to add counter to cover all lines

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What's with the other lines, you can have only one value. Or else I completely misunderstood your question.